# With php ibase is there any way of returning to the first row after reading several rows (to avoid re-querying the database)

Tags: php, firebird, interbase

With php ibase, ibase_query fetches the relation, several functions can then fetch rows from that relation, but all these functions extract **the next row**.

In Delphi I have the ability to return to the first row (`DataSet.First;`) - is there any equivalent in PHP ibase?

I could of course re-query the database, but this seems a waste of resources if the original relation is still accessible.

Example code:

```php
$table = ibase_query($sql);
$row = ibase_fetch_object($table);

while (!empty($row))
{
    echo $row->ENTRYNO.'<br>';
    $row = ibase_fetch_object($table);
}

//The missing functionality
$table.First;     
//or maybe
$row = ibase_fetch_object($table,first);  
     //in which case of course the following line would be redundant


$row = ibase_fetch_object($table);
while (!empty($row))
{
    //process record

    $row = ibase_fetch_object($table);
}
```

Comment: Never used ibase before but are you sure you aren't fetching twice, once initially then looping the fetch? Can you add the code? From https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ibase-fetch-assoc.php it seems like it would start at the first row, also seems strange if it were to start at second

Comment: Have added example code to show what I mean.

Comment: Yes,  like the other function ibase_fetch_assoc will fetch the first record first but then "Subsequent calls will return the next row in the result set" and there appears no ability to return to the first.

Answer (score 1):

The ibase/firebird-php driver is only able to fetch forward. If you want to consult earlier rows, you will need to store them yourself in some form, or execute the query again.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation.  That was the conclusion I was comming to.